# Create array from another array if values are same

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array -

```
Array
(
    [31] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
        )
    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )
)
```

Now for the key 31 both of the elements has same value ie 3 but not for the key 33. So I am trying to create another array which will look like.

```
Array
(
    [31] =>  same
    [33] =>  notsame       
)
```

That means if a key from multidimensional array has got all the values same then it will have the text 'same' else 'notsame'

My code-

```
foreach($subvaluesArr as $k1=>$v1) //$subvaluesArr is the multidimensional array here
    {
        foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2)
        {           
             if($v1[$k2] = $v1[$k2+1])
            {
                $newArr[$k1] = 'same';
            }
            else
            {
                $newArr[$k1] = 'notsame';
            }
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($newArr);
    echo '</pre>';
```

And the output is showing 'notsame' for both keys.

```
Array
(
    [31] => notsame
    [33] => notsame
)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: use `===` in `if` statement.

Comment: @AtaurRahman tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this snippet, you will get this error

> Notice: Undefined index: 2 in /in/bcqEH on line 14

See https://3v4l.org/bcqEH

This is because the code tries to compare first and second, *and* it tries to compare second and third element. But this third element doesn't exist. This means the comparison fails and sets the value to `notsame`.

To fix this, you could just compare the first two elements, e.g.

```
foreach ($subvaluesArr as $k1 => $v1) {
    if ($v1[0] == $v1[1]) {
        $newArr[$k1] = 'same';
    } else {
        $newArr[$k1] = 'notsame';
    }
}
```

When you really have more than two elements, you might try [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
foreach ($subvaluesArr as $k1 => $v1) {
    $u = array_unique($v1);
    if (count($u) == 1) {
        $newArr[$k1] = 'same';
    } else {
        $newArr[$k1] = 'notsame';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the array could have more than 2 elements. That's why I was doing +1 thing.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Working great. Thanks a lot Olaf.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `break;` loop after running the `if-else` condition.
example :

```
foreach($subvaluesArr as $k1=>$v1) //$subvaluesArr is the multidimensional array here
{
    foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2)
    {           
         if($v1[$k2] === $v1[$k2+1])
        {
            $newArr[$k1] = 'same';
        }
        else
        {
            $newArr[$k1] = 'notsame';
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the array has more than 2 elements then adding break doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

cant comment so I write it as answer. In your loop when you hit last element of an array, you ask

```
if($v1[$k2] == $v1[$k2+1])
```

where `$v1[$k2+1]` is "undefined" as you are out of bounds. So this last element is always false and you end up with "notsame"